# Character in php takes 3 places

Tags: php, arrays, string, reverse

I have a problem in string (array of characters) as a character take 3 places which make my code do unexpected result

check this code:

```
<?php
$input1="t’n";
for($i=0;$i<strlen($input1);$i++){
    echo $input1[$i] .'<br/>';
}
echo '<br>'.'=================='.'<br>';
$input2='test';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($input2);$i++){
    echo $input2[$i] .'<br/>';
}
echo '<br>'.'Strange ===> ';
echo $input1[1].$input1[2].$input1[3];
```

see the photo:
[image: CODE WITH THE OUTPUT]

As we noticed this character ’ take 3 places when deal with string as array of characters and the three must stay together to make the correct character.

I face this case when make a code that reverse a string I have input contain this character 
for example t’n => n’t
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the apostrophe you're checking in the string appears to be a different encoding that your text editor recognizes and handles, but your code is working with in it's standard encoding. I probably didn't phrase that the best, but hope you get what I mean. Standardize and sanitize your inputs and it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you. It's a test in a problem solving that does not pass this case. Is there any way to handle this with code?

Comment: Try to become familiar with searching the php manual. Pretty well documented. Maybe not the best way to do this, but I'll try a solution. (maybe someone with a better solution with show up)

Comment: I checked php manual but nothing found or what word I should search for?!

Comment: Don't know if you saw in my answer, but search for "encoding", and don't be afraid to read a lot. If you learn what you don't need this time, you'll still have it for next time. OR reverse engineer it yourself as Pierre describes.(will give you an even better understanding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, you can not play with a character string as with an array as long as it contains multibyte characters. Never mind, we'll use the mb_* functions to extract each character:

```
$input = 't’n';
$result = [];

for ($i=0, $max=mb_strlen($input); $i < $max; $i++) {
    $result[] = mb_substr($input, $i, 1); 
}

echo implode('<br>', $result);
```

Ok, it looks good and you can easily obtain a reversed string with `array_reverse`:

```
echo implode('', array_reverse($result));
```

But it isn't so simple. Let's consider a string with combining characters:

```
$input = "a\xcc\x80e"; // àe
```

This string has three code points:

- U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A (\x61)
- U+0300 COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT (\xcc\x80)
- U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E (\x65)

Problem: if we use the previous code to reverse this string, we obtain the three code points in a reverse order so the string `"e\xcc\x80a" // èa`. Note that the grave accent is now on the **e** and no more on the **a**.

To obtain the expected result **eà** (`"ea\xcc\x80"`), we have to work not with bytes, not with code points, but with graphemes. *(A grapheme includes the character and eventual characters combined with it).*

For that we can use [`grapheme_*` functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.intl.grapheme.php) instead of `mb_*` functions exactly the same way:

```
for ($i=0, $max=grapheme_strlen($input); $i < $max; $i++) {
    $result[] = grapheme_substr($input, $i, 1); 
}
```

Other possibility, we can use the `\X` pcre feature that matches a grapheme:

```
if ( preg_match_all('~\X~u', $input, $matches) ) {
    $result = $matches[0];
}
```

---

Nota Bene: You can obviously avoid to create an array to reverse a string:

```
function grapheme_strrev($input) {
    $result = '';
    for ($i = grapheme_strlen($input) - 1; $i > -1; $i--) {
        $result .= grapheme_substr($input, $i, 1);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That character is RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, U+2019 (the number is in hex). In UTF-8, it is encoded as e2 80 99. So when you reverse 74 e2 80 99 6e, you need to make 6e e2 80 99 74.

You can handle this in a byte string as follows:

- Iterate $i from the end of $input to the beginning.
- If $input[$i] is between 0 and 127 inclusive, copy it to the end of $output.
- If $input[$i] is between 128 and 191 (or between -128 and -65 if char is signed), hold it.
- If $input[$i] is between 192 and 255 (-64 and -1), copy it and the held bytes as a block to the end of $output.

All Unicode characters encoded in UTF-8 are either a 7-bit character as a byte with the high bit clear, or a multibyte sequence in which the first byte begins 11 and all the rest begin 10.

There are invalid sequences of bytes in UTF-8 (e.g. you'll never see the bytes fe and ff); how you handle them is up to you.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't working, and I don't have time to do more right now. But you should be able to use a couple functions to detect character encoding, and convert if necessary. I somehow doubt this is the goal of your exercise though... seems like a very expensive(computationally) check. Either way, search the manual for encoding functions, and do something similar to the below - you will be able to handle each character. For whatever reason I can't call the convert function successfully in my CLI.

```
<?php
$input1="t’n";
$ce = mb_internal_encoding(); //current encoding in use by php/this script by X configuration
for($i=0;$i<strlen($input1);$i++){
    if(mb_detect_encoding($input1[$i], "auto", true) == $ce){
        echo $input1[$i] .'<br/>';
    }
    else{
        echo mb_convert_encoding($input1[$i], $ce, "auto");
    }
}
echo '<br/>'.'=================='.'<br/>';
$input2='test';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($input2);$i++){
    echo $input2[$i] .'<br/>';
}
```

Sorry incomplete, hope this helps, or someone more knowledgeable than myself can jump in...

Comment: Why -1 for giving the right functions and pointing the right direction? I thought this wasn't supposed to be a copy and paste farm anyway... Or at least comment with a better method.